# What is the project.packagespec.json file?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

What is the `project.packagespec.json` file? I saw it in some .NET projects under the `obj` folder but couldn't find anything on Google/SO that explains it.

Comment: Everything inside `obj` folder is for build system. You don't need to looks there, unless you want to become MSBuild guru

Comment: OK, I want to become an MSBuild guru. What's the `project.packagespec.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project.packagespec.json` is automatically generated by the .NET SDK when building a project that uses the PackageReference format for managing NuGet packages. It contains metadata about the NuGet packages required by the project and is used by the SDK to restore the packages during the build process

Comment: Thanks, any source/further reading? Also, why is it usually not valid JSON?